# Converting a Map into a sorted TreeSet using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

The code is:

```
public TreeSet<VehicleTransportation> allVehicleTransportations(){
        
        Set<VehicleTransportation> sortedVehicles = allVehicleTransportation.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue.pollutionLevel , Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue.price))
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        return sortedVehicles;
    }
```

Where the HashMap is

```
HashMap<String, VehicleTransportation> allVehicleTransportation = new HashMap<String, VehicleTransportation>();
```

There are 2 problems I run into using this code. First, for some reason `Map.Entry::getValue` runs into the error :
`The target type of this expression must be a functional interface`
I think the problem here is that the comparator cannot compare between two objects of type `VehicleTransportation` although  `pollutionLevel` and `price` are both strings.

Second , I cannot quite figure out how to convert the Set into a TreeSet
(maybe use `(TreeSet<VehicleTransportation>)` ?)

Comment: `Map.Entry::getValue.pollutionLevel` is not valid Java syntax (`e -> e.getValue().pollutionLevel` is). Also, if you sort twice, the first sort is ignored (maybe you were looking for [`Comparator#thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-)?)

Comment: @knittl the first sort is not ignored, as the second sort will use a stable algorithm, however, it’s a very inefficient way to establish a secondary ordering criteria.

Comment: @Holger interesting, I wasn't aware of that. Is stable sort guaranteed or is it up to the implementation to provide one? Apart from the inefficiency, another disadvantage that doing it that way is not "sort by A, then sort by B", but rather the opposite/reverse "sort by B, but keep the order of the previous sort by A".

Comment: @Holger note that the docs state "For ordered streams, the sort is stable. For unordered streams, no stability guarantees are made." For an entrySet that might hold true, but the statement could be too general

Comment: @knittl whether `entrySet().stream()` creates an ordered stream, depends on the map. So, from what we see in the question, we can’t say whether the first `sorted` has to use a stable algorithm. But after the first `sorted` step, the stream is ordered, as the sorting defines an encounter order. So the second `sorted` must be stable. But you are right, `sorted(A).sorted(B)` is like `sorted(B.thenComparing(A))`. Since we only have that one code example and no alternative explanation of the task, this might be the intended order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A treeset is sorted anyway, so I would say the streams you are using to add to the treeset, even if it worked as you intend, the sorted items would be resorted according to their natural ordering, destroying any sort order that was created by the stream.

Instead, you should specify a sort order on the treeset, and then just addAll(VehicleTransportation.values()) and forget about streams! it will be sorted according to the sort order.

If you want to sort using streams, you'll have to return something other than the treeset (maybe an arrayList) which will not alter the sort order that you have defined.

Answer (score 3):

For reference, a non-streams version would look like something like this:

```
Comparator<VehicleTransportation> c = Comparator.comparing(VehicleTransportation::pollutionLevel)
                                                .reversed()
                                                .thenComparing(VehicleTransportation::price);
Set<VehicleTransportation> s = new TreeSet<>(c);
s.addAll(allVehicleTransportation.values());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need a TreeSet, there are other collectors for that:

```
    Set<VehicleTransportation> sortedVehicles = allVehicleTransportation.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue.pollutionLevel , Comparator.reverseOrder()))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue.price))
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<VehicleTransportation>()));
```

And since you don't want to sort using natural comparator, first create a comparator:

```
Comparator<VehicleTransportation> cmp =  Comparator.comparing(VehicleTransportation::getPollutionLevel()
          .thenComparing(VehicleTransportation::getPrice);
```

Then use it:

```
    Set<VehicleTransportation> sortedVehicles = allVehicleTransportation.entrySet().stream()
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<VehicleTransportation>(cmp)));
```

Do not perform a double sort !

Also, I'm pretty sure that performance on `Stream` sorted depends on the source and using a `TreeSet` (like above) might perform better because otherwise the `Stream` needs to sort which is not as easy as it seems: you may expect buffering of some sort which the `TreeSet` will do anyway.

**Edit:** per the comment below, if all you need is to collect and sort the values, this might be easier:

```
var set = new TreeSet<VehicleTransportation>(cmp);
set.addAll(allVehicleTransportation.values());
```

Comment: …and if you’re only interested in the values of a map, process `values()` in the first place, instead of using `entrySet()` and call `Map.Entry::getValue` on each entry. Since there’s no intermediate operation left then, the entire Stream operation becomes obsolete. Just use `var sortedVehicles  = new TreeSet<VehicleTransportation>(cmp); sortedVehicles .addAll(allVehicleTransportation.values());`

Answer (score 1):

You are using an incorrect syntax in your method references. On the right side of the operator `::` you should provide a method name, and nothing else.

You can substitute this faulty reference `Map.Entry::getValue.pollutionLevel` with a lambda expression:

```
entry -> entry.getValue().pollutionLevel()
```

*For more information on method references, have a look at this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).*

Sorting will make sense only if you are collecting the elements into a collection that preserves the order and is not sorted by itself, like `ArrayList`, `LinkedHashSet` or `ArrayDeque`. And there's no need to apply sorting twice. You will not get the same result as if you were sorting by two criteria in one go.

But in this case the data should be stored into a sorted collection, therefore sorting operation in the stream pipeline is redundant.

Instead of two separate *comparators*, you need a *comparator* that will establish the order of elements first by `pollutionLevel` and then by `price`. Which can be defined like that:

```
Comparator<VehicleTransportation> byLevelAndPrice =
    Comparator.comparing(VehicleTransportation::getPollutionLevel,
                         Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .thenComparing(VehicleTransportation::getPrice);
```

*Fore more information on how to build comparators with Java 8 methods have a look at this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-comparator-comparing).*

In order to create a `TreeSet` from values of a map, you can invoke `values()` and then immediately apply `collect()` by providing `Collectors.toCollection()` as an argument:

```
return allVehicleTransportation.values().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(byLevelAndPrice)));
```

Note that `Collectors.toSet()` will give you a general purpose implementation of the `Set` interface, which is currently a `HashSet`.